# rebuilding solution causes Could not load file or assembly on Razor 1.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my MVC3 solution, I have made some changes and when I go to debug after a rebuild, I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Doing a recursive GET fixes this, until I rebuild again, to see my changes, then the solution breaks with the same error. I haven't changed any of the web.config files and it is only c# code that is checked out.

If the assembly was not correct, then the recursive GET would still break the solution, surely? I'm not sure whats going wrong

Stack trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +556
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9885060
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered something similar coming off of my build server. The problem appears to be that a copy of System.Web.Mvc.dll is being copied into \bin that wasn't there on the last successful build and it, presumably, is making and/or misrouting the demand for System.Web.WebPages.Razor.

Deleting the unnecessary System.Web.Mvc.dll from the output \bin gets me back to Working As Expected.

Adding more .dlls to the output \bin (inclusive of System.Web.WebPages.Razor AND Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure) also gets me back to Working As Expected.

I would guess that the "new .dlls being added during build despite no code/project changes" is coming as a side effect of a bunch of build server patches from earlier this week.